# rdlc subreport in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rdlc

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public IList<PDetail> p_details { get; set; }
    }
    public class PDetail 
    {
        public string detail_name { get; set; }
    }
```

I have an object structure as above. I want to create rdlc report using this structure. I can use in the DataSet

```
    IList<Product> dataset = new List<Product>();
```

How can I do report to this dataset in report viewer(.rdlc). I use to mvc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you can't. Sql Reporting does not support nested object lists. I searched a lot for a solution to this problem. And the only thing I came around was to create a report, and inside of that a sub report to which i pass the child list of data. I found an article that explains how to do that, I hope this link can hel  you to.

[Reporting against a domain model](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2009/07/01/reporting-against-a-domain-model/)

What's possible, and i you may need in the future, is to use a nested object, by serializing the the classes. you can see in this blog article how to do that.

[ReportViewer - object datasource, nested objects](http://wraithnath.blogspot.ch/2011/04/reportviewer-object-datasource-nested.html)